# unable to load csv file from google forms

Tags: angular, google-forms, angular-http, angular-httpclient

```js
export class TopicComponent {

  csvUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DEhSS05msJGTV7rIZEPBjYFH_FK2G3o4okWTdi_Xxsc/edit?usp=sharing';
  csvData: any [] = [];
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

    readCsvData() {
      this.http.get(this.csvUrl)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.extractData(data),
        err => this.handleError(err)
      );
    }
 
    private extractData(res: any) {
      let csvData = res['_body'] || '';
    let allTextLines = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    let lines = [];

    for ( let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        // split content based on comma
        let data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length === headers.length) {
            let tarr = [];
            for ( let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
    this.csvData = lines;
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {
 
      let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
      return errMsg;
    }
```

```html
<h2>CSV data</h2>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn1 btn2" (click)="readCsvData()">Read Csv Data</button>
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div>
  <table border="1" class="demoTable">
    <tr *ngFor = "let x of csvData">
      <td *ngFor = "let y of x ">{{ y }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am linking google forms csv response to my angular app in form of table but
on execution, the following error is encountered -

Request header field X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

[here is the image of the error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dFIE.png)

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
In my case the reason was that in my Chrome cookies was saved X-XSRF-TOKEN field. And somehow Chrome added header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-xsrf-token' to OPTION request. In Firefox the same page works fine, in incognito mode Chrome - too. 
So I've just delete this cookies field (X-XSRF-TOKEN) and that's all.

Comment: Cleaned the chrome's browser history. Still not working.